# Retornar agrupamento em vetor MySql

Tags: php, mysql, array, query

Estou tentando montar uma consulta MySQL com vários inner joins, nessa consulta tem uma coluna que pode ou não vir duplicada, eu gostaria de colocar as linhas duplicadas por essa coluna em um vetor, usando o **GROUP BY**, a query retorna apenas um dos registros. Segue a consulta:

ETID: A idéia é agrupar as aulas de uma disciplina pelo dia da semana.

```
'SELECT `l`.`lnkId`, `s`.`schWeekDay`, `d`.`dscType`, `d`.`dscName`, `s`.`schStartAt`, `r`.`rmName`
FROM '.DATABASE['name'].'.`tblschedule` `s`
INNER JOIN '.DATABASE['name'].'.`tblstudent` `st`
    ON `st`.`stdCode` = :username 
INNER JOIN '.DATABASE['name'].'.`tbllinks` `l`
    ON `l`.`lnkUser` = `st`.`stdRegister`
INNER JOIN '.DATABASE['name'].'.`tbldiscipline` `d`
    ON `d`.`dscCode` = `s`.`schDiscipline`
INNER JOIN '.DATABASE['name'].'.`tblroom` `r`
    ON `r`.`rmId` = `s`.`schRoom`
WHERE `s`.`schDiscipline` = `l`.`lnkDiscipline`
    GROUP BY `s`.`schWeekDay`
    ORDER BY `s`.`schWeekDay`, `s`.`schStartAt`'
```

Eu gostaria de retornar algo to tipo:

```
Array(
[0] => Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [lnkId] => 61
            [schWeekDay] => 1
            [dscType] => DI
            [dscName] => Nome da Disciplina 1
            [schStartAt] => 19:20:00
            [rmName] => Sala 1
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [lnkId] => 62
            [schWeekDay] => 1
            [dscType] => DI
            [dscName] => Nome da Disciplina 1
            [schStartAt] => 20:10:00
            [rmName] => Sala 1
        )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [lnkId] => 63
        [schWeekDay] => 2
        [dscType] => DPDI
        [dscName] => Nome da Disciplina 2
        [schStartAt] => 19:20:00
        [rmName] => Sala 3
    )

)
```

Comment: cada posição poderia conter apenas 2 objetos?

Comment: Não tem um limite

Comment: mais voce quer separar eles pelo que? ou uma posicao contendo todos os objetos?

Comment: Quero agrupalas pelo dia da semana, por exemplo se existir mais de um registro no mesmo dia, ele deveria criar um vetor para colocar as linhas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A única solução que encontrei foi através do PHP mesmo sabendo que existe uma maneira melhor de se fazer:

```
// Se a requisição ocorrer com sucesso
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    // Se algum registro for encontrado
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $group = [1 => [], 2 => [], 3 => [], 4 => [], 5 => []];

        // Filtrar os valores por dia da semana
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $key) {
            switch ($key->schWeekDay) {
                case '1': $group[1][] = $key; break;
                case '2': $group[2][] = $key; break;
                case '3': $group[3][] = $key; break;
                case '4': $group[4][] = $key; break;
                case '5': $group[5][] = $key; break;
                default: break;
            } // switch
        } // foreach

        // Retornar os dados para o cliente
        echo json_encode([
            'error' => false,
            'data' => $group
        ], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR); // echo

        return;
    } // if

    // Se nenhum dado for encontrado
    throw new RuntimeException('Nenhum registro encontrado!');
} // if

// Se ocorrer algum erro durante a requisição
throw new RuntimeException('Erro ao conectar-se com o servidor!');
```

Que resultou no seguinte array:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lnkId] => 61
                [schWeekDay] => 1
                [dscType] => DI
                [dscName] => Disciplina teste 1
                [schStartAt] => 19:20:00
                [rmName] => Sala 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lnkId] => 61
                [schWeekDay] => 1
                [dscType] => DI
                [dscName] => Disciplina teste 1
                [schStartAt] => 20:40:00
                [rmName] => Sala 1
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lnkId] => 61
                [schWeekDay] => 1
                [dscType] => DI
                [dscName] => Disciplina teste 1
                [schStartAt] => 21:30:00
                [rmName] => Sala 1
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lnkId] => 63
                [schWeekDay] => 2
                [dscType] => DPDI
                [dscName] => Disciplina teste 2
                [schStartAt] => 19:20:00
                [rmName] => Sala 3
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lnkId] => 62
                [schWeekDay] => 3
                [dscType] => DPDI
                [dscName] => Disciplina teste 3
                [schStartAt] => 19:20:00
                [rmName] => Sala 2
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lnkId] => 64
                [schWeekDay] => 3
                [dscType] => DI
                [dscName] => Disciplina teste 4
                [schStartAt] => 19:20:00
                [rmName] => Sala 4
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lnkId] => 65
                [schWeekDay] => 5
                [dscType] => DI
                [dscName] => Disciplina teste 5
                [schStartAt] => 19:20:00
                [rmName] => Sala 5
            )

    )

)
```